# pyserial read to USB-to-UART device fails with hw flow control on Windows 10

Tags: windows, pyserial, flow-control

I have a Silicon Labs CP2102 USB to UART Bridge device. I am writing some python to script writing/reading data to a serial device with pyserial on Windows 10.

It works fine without flow control. However, it fails to read and times out if I enable either DSR/DTR or RTS/CTS.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 230400
ser.port = "COM13"
ser.dtr = 1
ser.dsrdtr = True
ser.write_timeout = 1
ser.timeout = 1
ser.open()

n = ser.write(bytes([1]))
n += ser.write(bytes([2]))
n += ser.write(bytes([3]))
print("bytes written ", n)

byte_read = []
byte_read += ser.read(1)
byte_read += ser.read(1)
byte_read += ser.read(1)
print(byte_read)

ser.close()
```

The same device works fine with TS232 terminal tools, like Termite or TeraTerm, on Windows 10.

It seems like an issue with pyserial.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19319414/8777946
```ser.xonxoff=True```

Comment: xonxoff is for software-based flow control, I am after the hardware-based ones

Answer (score 0):

The [pyserial documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.set_output_flow_control) appears to allude that hardware flow control is not supported with Windows.

```
set_output_flow_control(enable)
  Platform: Posix (HW and SW flow control)
  Platform: Windows (SW flow control only)
```

However, [Amulek1416](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/89#issuecomment-811932067) appears to have come up with a solution that might work if you want to manually toggle the flow control:

```
import time
import serial

#Since we are doing the RTS and CTS logic ourselves, keep rtscts=False
mySerial = serial.Serial(port='COMX', baudrate=9600, rtscts=False)

# To send some information:

dataToSend = 'HelloWorld!'
mySerial.setRTS(True)

# Wait for CTS signal
while not mySerial.getCTS():
    pass

mySerial.write(bytes(dataToSend, 'ascii'))
time.sleep(0.25) # Wait for the data to have sent before disabling RTS
mySerial.setRTS(False)
```